# split words by comma while reading line by line. c

Tags: c, arrays, split

I have text with lines like that: (first word): word2,word3,...

> ab: 1a,2b,3c,4d
>
> c: 5e,6f,7g

I want to assign the right side into arrays like that:

```
arr1[4] = {1a,2b,3c,4d}
arr2[3] = {5e,6f,7g}
```

Now I iterate line by line like this

```
 while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ){...}
```

Can you suggest a way to split the lines such that I can take each word separately without the first word and the commas?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
while (...) {
    if (!strtok(line, ": ,"))
        continue;

    while ((word = strtok(NULL, ": ,")))
        /* ... */
}
```